# XSLT remove child nodes and keep whitespaces with punctuation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML file with `<mixed-citation>` format which includes some untagged content like whitespaces and punctuation:

```
<ref>
    <mixed-citation publication-type="book">
        <collab>Collab</collab>. <source>Source</source>. <publisher-loc>Location</publisher-loc>: <publisher-name>Name</publisher-name>; <month>Jul</month> <year>2020</year>. [comment].
        <uri xlink:href="https://www.google.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">URL</uri>
    </mixed-citation>
</ref>
```

And I managed to build this semi-functional XSLT so far which copies all node values, keeps whitespaces and punctuation and also removes two child nodes "month" and "uri":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <html>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref/mixed-citation">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space()'/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref//month">
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref//uri">
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to create simple output HTML file which would look like this:

```
<html>
   <p>
      <p>Collab. Source. Location: Name; 2020. [comment].</p>
   </p>
</html
```

But with the provided XSLT file I am getting wrong output like this:

```
<html>
   <p>
      <p>Collab.Source.Location:Name;2020. [comment].</p>
   </p>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe an alternative approach to this without using identity transform?

**UPDATE:**

With the solution provided below by @zx485 the output is correct only if `<month>` and `<uri>` are both excluded. If I still leave them there, then output is wrong:

```
<p>Collab. Source. Location: Name; Jul2020. [comment].URL</p>
```

It should be:

```
<p>Collab. Source. Location: Name; Jul 2020. [comment]. URL</p>
```

Transformation template should actually just parse all the tags, no matter which children are excluded, and always leave all pre-defined whitespaces and punctuation in-place. It should only strip some leading/trailing spaces inside tags if they accidentally appear: i.e. `<month> Jul </month>` to `<month>Jul</month>`.

Also, the doubled output was my mistake, I fixed the output above.

Comment: Is the target format HTML? Do you need the display of whitespace in the rendering of the output HTML or in the source code of the output HTML? Given that HTML user agents collapse white space it seems that the rendering of a `p` with plain text would not differ with e.g. `<p>foo   bar</p>` and `<p>foo bar</p>`. Therefore it seems simply using the built-in text only copy behaviour, with templates for the elements you need to transform to HTML elements, should give the desired output in the rendered HTML.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to have the correct spaces in the HTML source code as well. So, yes, having `<p>foo bar</p>` in this case would be great. However, this is good thinking. Rendered HTML output is the same in each case. Besides, each parsed reference in the end is clear-text, tagged with `<p>` element, nothing else. Actually in the case above, I'm just wondering why `</collab>. <source>` gets parsed to . with one trailing space, but between `</month> <year>` the space is gone? Is there any other approach I should use for this? The more I think, the more complicated it seems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense the set of your templates to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <html>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ref/mixed-citation">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="mixed-citation/*/text() | mixed-citation/text()[last()]">
        <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(.)'/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mixed-citation/text()[position() != last()]">
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="ref//(month|uri)" />
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above set of templates copies all `text()` nodes which are not the `last()` and omits all `month` and `uri` elements that are children of `ref`.

The `mixed-citation/*/text() | mixed-citation/text()[last()]` template rule omits the leading and trailing spaces of all grand-children of `mixed-citation` or of the `last()` `text()` node of `mixed-citation`.

The result is as desired:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <p>
      <p>Collab. Source. Location: Name; 2020. [comment].</p>
   </p>
</html>
```

---

This solution does not double the output.
If that's really what you wanted and not an error, you'd have to double the `<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>` in the `<xsl:template match="ref/mixed-citation">` template.

Comment: Thank you for provided solution. It partially works, please check the update above. Maybe I wasn't clear enough initially, the xslt should always keep the according whitespaces and punctuation, no matter which elements are removed.

Comment: This is unsolvable in a general way, and this is why: `<month>Jul</month>` would require an additional space after "Jul", but `<uri ...>URL</uri>` would require one _before_ "URL`. So it's not really about only preserving space, but rather about adding/removing space according to certain conditions. Preserving all space could easily be achieved by `<xsl:value-of select="string(/ref/mixed-citation)" />`.

Comment: I thought a lot about the spacing issues above and at the end it really seems the issue is unsolvable without special conditions. Thank you for an answer!